# How to change the axis scale of a boxplot in seaborn using a dataframe with pandas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, yaxis

I have created a seaborn boxplot graph for investment data ranging from $100,000 to $40,000,000, spread out over several years. The graph shows a boxplot for investment amounts per year. The data comes from two series in a dataframe, which I'm rendering from a CSV: investment year ('inv_year') and investment amount ('inv_amount').

**The problem:** the graph's y-axis is automatically shown in increments of 0.5, so:

```
0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, etc. (i.e. in tens of millions)
```

but I want the axis in increments of 5, so:

```
0, 5, 10, 15, etc. (i.e. in millions)
```

How do I change the axis's scale?

Here's my current code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('investments'))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
sns.boxplot(x='inv_year', y='inv_amount', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array with the specified ticks and pass it to `plt.yticks`:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 5))
```

If you want to keep the limits but just adjust the ticks:

```
increments = 5
ax = plt.gca()
start, end = ax.get_ylim()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, increments))
```

Comment: Thanks, runDOSrun. I tried both strategies (and imported the numpy library) on PyCharm. The first strategy returns a NameError where "name 'x' is not defined." The latter launches Python, but the program gets stuck before showing a graph (bouncing in my dock indefinitely). Am I leaving something out of my code?

Comment: @shraz I've provided you a general solution and not something to copy/paste (since you haven't provided the data necessary to reproduce your problem). You'll need to adapt it to your own code which shouldn't be an issue if you put some effort into **understanding** it first (e.g. `x` is your y-data). If anything is unclear, let me know.

Comment: sure. I indeed had attempted to replace x with my y-data, but since the launcher was getting stuck, I was wondering whether it indicated a problem in PyCharm or my machine. But all good; I'll dig around further.